# CancelledError: [_Derived_]RecvAsync is cancelled. Running on google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am getting the following error when fitting my model. Occurs after every 5th epoch!

[Link to notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rC5vXmvqNRWh-Qr17cxJVX96_HLu_N6M?usp=sharing)

[Tensorflow, Keras, Cuda versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNpi5.png)

Tried the following options:

1. TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH=1
2. Changing cuda and keras versions.

Error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-21-44f42c6a15c1>:2: Model.fit_generator (from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use Model.fit, which supports generators.
Epoch 1/10
39/39 [==============================] - 10s 248ms/step - loss: 4.7112 - accuracy: 0.1422 - val_loss: 4.2005 - val_accuracy: 0.1601
Epoch 2/10
39/39 [==============================] - 8s 207ms/step - loss: 3.9892 - accuracy: 0.1991 - val_loss: 3.9835 - val_accuracy: 0.1725
Epoch 3/10
39/39 [==============================] - 8s 214ms/step - loss: 3.7736 - accuracy: 0.2169 - val_loss: 3.6771 - val_accuracy: 0.2279
Epoch 4/10
39/39 [==============================] - 8s 211ms/step - loss: 3.5558 - accuracy: 0.2519 - val_loss: 3.5377 - val_accuracy: 0.2499
Epoch 5/10
39/39 [==============================] - 8s 213ms/step - loss: 3.4118 - accuracy: 0.2714 - val_loss: 3.2555 - val_accuracy: 0.2810
Epoch 6/10
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CancelledError:  [_Derived_]RecvAsync is cancelled.
     [[{{node broadcast_weights_1/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/else/_13/broadcast_weights_1/assert_broadcastable/AssertGuard/Assert/data_1/_74}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_11025]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Comment: This error appears to be solved by using `import os
os.environ["TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH"]="true"`. Thanks!

Comment: I did this too, but no luck in my case.. :'(

Comment: I got the same issure here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65160085/getting-cancellederror-derived-recvasync-is-cancelled-after-hours-of-train)). I am getting it in seemingly random order. May I ask: Is the training-data always in the same order for you? I am starting to suspect the model inputs to be the cause for this.

Comment: Can you try with reducing batch_size. Thanks

Comment: I was using a custom batch generator using yield.... Hence, I re-implemented a batch generator as in Keras Documentation and this resolved my issue. I also had to use tf.convert_to_tensor() when passing the input to my model... hope that helps someone...

Comment: Rest I tried all the solutions of playing with batch_sizes and ["TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH"]="true" , but didn't work for me...

Comment: I have the same problem when the validation set is large (no problem when the validation set is small), is there any way to evaluation the validation set on cpu while training on gpu? Looking for a solution too

Answer (score 0):

In my case upgrading tensorflow and other packages solved the issue. I used an anaconda environment with the following configurations:

1. tensorflow from v2.3.0 to v.2.6.0
2. cudnn from v7.6.0 to 8.2.1
3. cudatoolkit from v10.1.168-0 to 11.3.1